# validate string which has only one special character using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are several question like this  on Stack-overflow, but I can't seem to get a straight answer out of the questions already posted.Looking forward if someone can help me.

**I want to validate** a string & return `TRUE` if it satisfies below condition

- String contains  only one special character i.e  _  (underscore)
- & this special character should not appear at beginning or end of the string

Example:

```
     var demo1="23dsfXXXa32_XXXX"  // Valid, should returns TRUE
     var demo2="_23dsfXXXa32_XXXX" // Invalid,should returns FALSE
     var demo3= "23dsfXXXa32XXXX_" //invalid,should returns FALSE
     var demo4= "_" //invalid,should returns FALSE
     var demo5= "&sdfsa_XX";// returns false
```

Tried: [`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/6fp6uyf4/1/)

```
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$/.test(demo1) == true) {
   alert('Valid String');
}
```

Result: Not functioning as per expected

Comment: Curt , thanks for Edit

Comment: Does the character *have* to appear?

Comment: Cant you just use `if(string.indexOf("_") === 0 || string.indexOf("_") === string.length-1)` ? Regex is so complicated for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've said you *require* that the character be there, one way is to do it with a regular expression is with a negated character class at each end with a non-negated one in the middle:

```
var rex = /^[^_]+[_][^_]+$/;
```

That only handle underscores; add other "special" characters to all three character classes there.

How that works:

- `^` matches start of string
- `[^_]+` requires one or more characters *not* in the class
- `[_]` requires exactly one character *in* the class
- `[^_]+` requires one or more characters *not* in the class
- `$` matches end of string

Comment: I mean only numbers(0-9) & English alphabet(a-Z) & _ (single)  is valid combination

Comment: @Ashutosh: Thats fine, just add the relevant characters in the classes above.

Answer (score -1):

You could simplify it by using `indexOf` to verify that its not in the first or last position and `split` to see if its there only once. This is usually faster than a regex pattern.

```
function checkString(str){
    return str.indexOf("_") !== 0 && str.indexOf("_") !== str.length-1 && str.split("_") === 2;
}
```